# Remove all values present in "list_b" from "list_a"

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and to coding, and I am running in to a challenge.  I am trying to remove all values from "list_a" that are present in "list_b."  The inputs passed through the function must be lists, they can't be any other data type.

For example,  [1,2,2,2,3],  [2]  should return [1, 3].

My attempt is below, but it returns [1, 2, 3] which is wrong.  I'm stuck and would appreciate some help on how to do this the right way, please.

```
def changeup(list_a, list_b):
    for i in list_b:
        for k in list_a:
            if k == i:
                list_a.remove(k)

    return list_a

changeup([1,2,2,2,3],[2])

#This is returning [1, 2, 3].  It should be returning [1, 3].  Not sure why?
```

Comment: Mutating list while iterating through is not the correct way to do it. It produces undesired results. Instead work on copy of the list you want to modify.

Comment: Additionally, in the interest of better readability, that you would reserve i for going over a list by its index.
`for item_a in list a` would be better, in my opinion.

Comment: You are iterating on list_a and that the same time removing items in it.
You may copy this to a temp list and operate on that copy

    def changeup(list_a, list_b):
        from copy import copy
        list_a_cp = copy(list_a)
        for i in list_b:
            for k in list_a:
                if k == i:
                    list_a_cp.remove(k)
    
        return list_a_cp
    
    changeup([1,2,2,2,3],[2])

    Out:[1, 3]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_a = list(set([item for item in list_a if item not in list_b]))
```

If you want want to keep duplicated values.

```
list_a = [item for item in list_a if item not in list_b]
```

Iterate through one list to see if the item is in the other

Comment: This is a `O(m * n)` solution; proper use of `set` could get it down to `O(m + n)` (and still avoid discarding duplicates) so long as the values are hashable. `set_b = frozenset(list_b)` then `list_a = [item for item in list_a if item not in set_b]`.